# Threading clarification

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

I have general architecture level question on below scenarios.

I have lots of sub systems like components in my product.

is it good to keep each subsystem as a separate process ? or is it good to keep all subsystems in separate threads in a single process ?

All my subsystems will be interacting each other for giving/getting data from each other.

Comment: This question seems to be just another form of "can you explain what processes and threads are?". Please research first.

Comment: I knew that process , thread and all fundas. I meant to ask , becoz of   > any performance > if any crash on thread , protection of other thread etc... Expecting just a thoughts on this....

Comment: I did read the question and I don't see how someone who knows "process, thread and all fundas" already cannot answer it. You already know if a thread crashes what happens because you know the fundas. You already know the performance. What are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with threading is that in order to safely pass data directly between them you'll need some form of synchronisation between them. Do this often enough and you'll remove any advantages that you may have from using multiple threads.

My own practice is to not use threads unless there is an absolute need. Often I'll use more threading if I'm interfacing with hardware of some sort such as serial or network devices as these can slow system response down drastically.

I tend to go with the rule that a thread should be able to run on it's own with little (if any) interaction with any other code. If a section of code is heavily reliant on another then they shouldn't be placed in separate threads.

You should design a system that works first (by all means place subsystem code in separate libraries) and then if performance is an issue look to see if there are any benefits from threading. By doing it this way you avoid the hassle of debugging threads until absolutely necessary.

As they say Keep It Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Without a good reason or need to create a task? Just use a thread.